# Creating a plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and i need to create a plugin using wordpress. Can you say defaultly how much files I need to create for a whole plugin and how it works? Can you with one example.. Advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here i found a guide, may be it can help you in differentiating Actions & Filters
[Beginners guide for Actions & Filters](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters--wp-27373)